# How can I set an element's orientation along a motion path properly?

Tags: html, svg, path

Whenever I put "rotate="auto" or "rotate="auto-reverse" the rectangle is flying chaotically all over the place. How can i fix that?

```html
<svg width="800" height="600">
  <rect x="200" y="300" width="40" height="15" fill="black">
  <animateMotion dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite"
     rotate="auto"
     path="M200,0 m-200,0 a200,200 0 1,0 400,0 a200,200 0 1,0 -400,0" /> </rect>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the origin of the SVG, and thus of the `<rect>` is at (0,0) - the top left.  When you have auto rotation on, the rectangle is swinging around that origin point while also following the motion path.

The solution is to move the `<rect>` to the origin, so that the rotation happens around a point in the rect.

```html
<svg width="800" height="600">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="40" height="15" fill="black">
    <animateMotion dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite"
       rotate="auto"
       path="M200,0 m-200,0 a200,200 0 1,0 400,0 a200,200 0 1,0 -400,0" />
  </rect>
</svg>
```

This also means that the centre of the rect is following your motion path, and it is not offset (by x="200" y="300").

Of course, this now means that the motion is not where you want it to be.  The best solution to that, in general, is to wrap both elements in a group (`<g>`) element that shifts everything to the desired location with a `transform`.

```html
<svg width="800" height="600">
  <g  transform="translate(200,300)">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="40" height="15" fill="black">
      <animateMotion dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite"
         rotate="auto"
         path="M200,0 m-200,0 a200,200 0 1,0 400,0 a200,200 0 1,0 -400,0" />
    </rect>
  </g>
</svg>
```